# DVC pull returns ERROR: configuration error - Failed to authenticate GDrive remote: name: drive version: v2

Tags: dvc

I ran this github actions workflow with several variations, but I cannot pull the data from DVC.

```
name: auto-testing
on: [push]
jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: iterative/setup-dvc@v1
      - name: Get data
        run: |
          echo '---'
          echo GDRIVE_CREDENTIALS_DATA: $GDRIVE_CREDENTIALS_DATA
          echo '---'
          #pip list
          dvc remote default storage
          #dvc remote modify storage --local gdrive_use_service_account true
          #dvc remote modify storage --local gdrive_service_account_json_file_path .dvc/gdrive-access.json
          dvc pull
        env:
          REPO_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          #GDRIVE_CREDENTIALS_DATA : ${{ secrets.GDRIVE_CREDENTIALS_DATA }}   
      - name: Install requirements
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests
        run: python src/test.py
```

GDRIVE_CREDENTIALS_DATA is populated with the contents of the json file that I donwloaded from google and it was tested on two other computers. I tried using the environment variable as well as adding the json file to the repo to see if it would work. But no. I am getting this error message:

> ERROR: configuration error - Failed to authenticate GDrive remote: name: drive  version: v2
> ERROR: Failed to authenticate GDrive remote
> Learn more about configuration settings at https://man.dvc.org/remote/modify.
> Error: Process completed with exit code 251.

Comment: Hey, I think this is related / caused by https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/7949 - please come and add your comment.